# Add parameter to context without webhook in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

Im wondering if it is possible to add set matched entity properties as context. 
I am describing my use case which hopefully clarifies why I am trying to do this:
Imagine I have a entityType called "Animals" with the following properties -> synonyms mappings

```
{
    Cow: ['Mammal','Moo'],
    Frog: ['Amphibian','Croak']
    Dog: ['Mammal','Bark']
}
```

I have an Intent("Intent1") which has Animals entityType as a parameter

Use case 1: If Intent1 is called I want to add the matched animal in context. For example if the user says "Bark", I want to add "Dog" in context. I would also like to have a follow up intent to intent1 (call it Intent2) which displays the matched animal from context.How can I make this work

Use case 2: I want to get matched with one and only one animal such that when Intent2 is invoked it only displays one matched animal not many. So for example if Intent1 is invoked with "mammal", I want to add "Cow" and "Dog" in context .Such that when intent1 is invoked again it only tries to create  a match from the earlier matched entities. Thus if the user says Croak after having said Mammal then Frog should not get matched.

So the workflow should be:

```
Intent1 invoked with "Mammal" -> ["Cow","Dog"] put in context
Intent1 invoked with "Croak" -> ["Cow","Dog"] remain in context
Intent2 is invoked -> "Please narrow down to one animal"
Intent1 is invoked with "Dog" -> "Dog" is put in context
Intent2 is invoked -> Your matched animal is "Dog"
```

PS: I would prefer a solution without a Webhook

Answer (score 1):

When you add a parameter to an intent that has a output context, the parameters are automatically added to the outputContext. As long as the context is available you should be retrieve the parameters in your follow-up intent by using `#[ContextName].[ParameterName]`.

**Intent1**

[image]

**Intent 2**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

**Usecase 2**

Since you prefer an option without webhook, your options are a bit limited. It's not possible to narrow down on the available entity values based on what the user said. Dialogflow will always attempt to match the user input to all available values of an entity.

If you decided to use a webhook, you would have a second option. You could set "Dog" and "Cow" in the context and if the user gets invoked again, you check the user input against the values in your context. If the user says "Croak" you can return a no match response via code.